# Are there any limitations on the number of bytes for writing in Chan's FAT FILE SYSTEM MODULE?

Tags: c, filesystems, embedded, sd-card, cortex-m

I'm using the ARM Cortex-M7 (ATMEL processor) whit [Chan's FAT File System Module](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) and I have a problem when writing a file with a non-multiply byte amount of SECTOR_SIZE_DEFAULT (512 bytes).

After a loop where I write a file using the f_write() function with different lengths of bytes (not multiple SECTOR_SIZE_DEFAULT), some characters appear wrong.

Here's the main part where the writing happens:

```
            f_open(&FileObject, filename_aux, FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
            do
            {
                len = getAviableData(buf);

                f_write(&FileObject, , buf, len, (UINT*)&ByteWritten);

                total += len;

            }while(total < MAX_LEN)
            f_close(&FileObject);
```

When I write it to another memory without File System, I do not have any problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You are doing something wrong.  FATfs works fine for 'general' file sizes IME.

Comment: Should 'total += len;' not be 'total += ByteWritten;' ?

Comment: FafFs does not define the target specific I/O driver - it is not at all clear that that is not where your problem lies - most likely I'd say.  What version? And who supplied the I/O layer (or did you write your own)?  Are you using SPI or SDIO?  The Cortex-M tag is not helpful;, it is a peripheral I/O issue not an ARM core issue - what is the actual target?.

Comment: It is not helpful either that thsi is not "real" code - the `f_write()` call is syntactically incorrect (extra comma), so is evidently not the code you are running.

Comment: @Clifford IME, if the '512' IO driver below FATfs does not work correctly, you cannot even mount the drive.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit : There are any number of ways that it could be wrong that would still allow it to partially work or work unreliably. Moreover mounting the file system is a read-only operation, the error appears to be in the write.  My point is merely that fatFs works in an enormous number of projects - I have been using it for years - while the porting layer that is unique to the user's project and platform is by definition less mature and deserving of consideration _first_. I know by diskio layer was not perfect first time, but mostly worked in any case; breaking only in very specific usage.

Comment: @Clifford 'Moreover mounting the file system is a read-only operation' - oh yeah, good point!   My '512' drivers didn't work first time either, (in fact, once it took a week to get the SD-card to initialize OK) :(

Comment: The Microcontroller is a ATSAME70 (ARM Cortex-M7) with High Speed Multimedia Card Interface (HSMCI). The HSMCI supports the SD Memory Card Specification V2.0.

Comment: I'm working with the DCache enabled and the I/O Driver based on the Atmel storage example provided by IAR.

Comment: The Driver is configured to work with DMA. Can there be a concurrency problem? It may be necessary to add a memory barrier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
f_open(&FileObject, filename_aux, FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
do
{
        /* Cache Maintenance */
        SCB_CleanDCache_by_Addr((uint32_t *)buf, BUF_MAX_SIZE);

        len = getAviableData(buf);

        f_write(&FileObject, buf, len, (UINT*)&ByteWritten);

        /* Data Memory Barrier */
        __DMB();

        total += ByteWritten;

}while(total < MAX_LEN)
f_close(&FileObject);
```

Note that I added a DCache Maintenance and a Data Memory Barrier.

The file is now written correctly without errors.

Thanks.